# Pairwise graphical comparison of several distributions

Tags: r, heatmap, density-plot, ggally

This is an edited version of a previous question.

We are given an *m* by *n* table of *n* observations (samples) over *m* variables (genes, etc), and we are looking to study behavior of the variables between each pair of observations - For instance the two observations having the highest positive or negative correlation. For this purpose I have seen a great chart in Stadler et.al. Nature paper (2011):

[image]

Here it could be a sample dataset to be used.

```
m <- 1000
samples <- data.frame(unif1 = runif(m), unif2 = runif(m, 1, 2), norm1 = rnorm(m), 
                      norm2 = rnorm(m, 1), norm3 = rnorm(m, 0, 5))
```

I have already tested `gpairs(samples)` of package `gpairs` that produces this one. It's a good start, but has no option to put correlation coefficients on the upper-right section, nor the density plots on the lower corner:

[image]

Next I used `ggpairs(samples, lower=list(continuous="density"))` of package `GGally` (Thanks @LucianoSelzer for a comment below). Now we have correlations on the upper corner and the densities on the lower corner, but we are missing the diagonal barplots, and the density plots are not heatmap shaped.

[image]

Any ideas to make the more closer to the desired picture (the first one)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try to combine several different plotting methods and combine the results. Here's an example, which could be tweaked accordingly:

```
cors<-round(cor(samples),2) #correlations

# make layout for plot layout
laymat<-diag(1:5) #histograms
laymat[upper.tri(laymat)]<-6:15 #correlations
laymat[lower.tri(laymat)]<-16:25 #heatmaps

layout(laymat) #define layout using laymat

par(mar=c(2,2,2,2)) #define marginals etc.

# Draw histograms, tweak arguments of hist to make nicer figures
for(i in 1:5) 
  hist(samples[,i],main=names(samples)[i])

# Write correlations to upper diagonal part of the graph
# Again, tweak accordingly
for(i in 1:4)
  for(j in (i+1):5){
    plot(-1:1,-1:1, type = "n",xlab="",ylab="",xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
    text(x=0,y=0,labels=paste(cors[i,j]),cex=2)
    }

# Plot heatmaps, here I use kde2d function for density estimation
# image function for generating heatmaps
library(MASS)
for(i in 2:5)
  for(j in 1:(i-1)){
     k <- kde2d(samples[,i],samples[,j])
     image(k,col=heat.colors(1000))
    }
```

edit: Corrected indexing on the last loop.
[image: pairwise plot]

Comment: Wow! That's great, thank you. I am curious to see if there is any great and short ggplot2 answer as well.

Comment: I bet there is, I have just started to familiarize myself with ggplot2, so I decided to go old way. ggplot2 uses grid graphics, so the layout idea doesn't work there. But this might be helpful: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this using three different packages and two different functions as below:

`cor_fun` is for the upper triangle correlative calculation.
`my_fn`  is for the lower triangle plotting

You also need `ggpairs`.

```
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

m <- 1000
samples <- data.frame(unif1 = runif(m), unif2 = runif(m, 1, 2), norm1 = rnorm(m), 
                      norm2 = rnorm(m, 1), norm3 = rnorm(m, 0, 5))

cor_fun <- function(data, mapping, method="pearson", ndp=2, sz=5, stars=TRUE){ #ndp is to adjust the number of decimals
  
  x <- eval_data_col(data, mapping$x)
  y <- eval_data_col(data, mapping$y)
  
  corr <- cor.test(x, y, method=method)
  est <- corr$estimate
  lb.size <- sz 
  
  if(stars){
    stars <- c("***", "**", "*", "")[findInterval(corr$p.value, c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 1))]
    lbl <- paste0(round(est, ndp), stars)
  }else{
    lbl <- round(est, ndp)
  }
  
  ggplot(data=data, mapping=mapping) +
    annotate("text", x=mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), y=mean(y, na.rm=TRUE), label=lbl, size=lb.size)+
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.background=element_rect(fill="snow1")) 
  
}

colfunc<-colorRampPalette(c("darkblue","cyan","yellow","red"))

my_fn <- function(data, mapping){
  p <- ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) + 
    stat_density2d(aes(fill=..density..), geom="tile", contour = FALSE) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = colfunc(100)) + theme_classic()
}


ggpairs(samples, columns = c(1,2,3,4,5),
        lower=list(continuous=my_fn),
        diag=list(continuous=wrap("densityDiag", fill="gray92")), #densityDiag is a function
        upper=list(continuous=cor_fun)) + theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="white")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 1, color = "black")) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 1 , color = "black"))
```

[image]